# Persisting metadata over a map in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I was wondering the best way to accomplish this:

> Pass along metadata important for the pipeline, but not actually part of the value

Here's what I have:

```
 ; Attach the metadata
 ^{:doc "How obj works!"} [1 2 3]
 ; [1 2 3]

 ; ensure that it's attached
 (meta ^{:doc "How obj works!"} [1 2 3])
 ; {:doc "How obj works!"}

 ; map over the values
 (map inc ^{:doc "How obj works!"} [1 2 3])
 ; [2 3 4]

 ; try and get the metadata after the map
 (meta (map inc ^{:doc "How obj works!"} [1 2 3]))
 ; nil
```

I'm pretty sure I know **why** this is happening, but I'd like to know if there's a good way to do this, or if there's a better way to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding a better way, there probably is. If I had an object substantial enough to require a metadata docstring explaining how it works, I think I would define records or types, and maybe a protocol.

Without knowing what you're doing or why, however, I have no informed opinion on the matter.

If you are certain you want to `map` a function and preserve metadata, you could try something along the outline of the following:

```
(defn meta-preserving-map
  [f & cs]
  (let [data (apply merge (map meta cs))]
    (with-meta (apply map f cs) data)))
```